# spontaneously quitting kernel, assignment and packed arrays

Tags: error-tracking, packed-arrays

I am having an issue where the kernel spontaneously quits, deep in a long code that I have used for quite some time without this issue.
I've tracked it down to an assignment of the form:

> a[[All, All, All, -1]] = b;

Where the left and right hand side are both lists of machine precision complex numbers, both of dimension `{2,3,9}`, and the left hand side all zeroes. So nothing crazy there, and I can also print both sides before the assignment without issues. Neither is a packed array. Some entries were real rather than complex, but adding `0. I` didn't help.

The problem goes away by either of these methods (independently):

1. use arbitrary precision instead of machine precision
2. Modify the input so as to make some elements of the left hand side above nonzero (and it matters where)
3. I said above neither `a` nor `b` are packed arrays, but `a` *was* constructed from a packed array, i.e. an expression containing `` Developer`ToPackedArray[c] ``, and changing that to just `c` also fixes it.

So it seems the issue has to do with packed arrays, as 3 gets rid of that explicitly, 1 indirectly, and 2 perhaps affects whether/how/which part was converted in a packed array in the first place.
Also, using `On["Packing"]`, methods 1 and 3 get rid of unpacking warnings (occuring in construction of a, not in the line above itself.), method 2 does not.

Does this make sense? Is there an easy way to check if an expression *contains* rather than *is* a packed array?
And how to avoid this? Is the rule not to use packed arrays when still assigning to parts of the expression?

Comment: ``Catch[expr /. x_?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> Throw[True]]``?  Not sure about the rest. Code to reproduce the problem may be needed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, that returns True, but when I try to find all occurrences using `Cases[expr,x_?Developer`PackedArrayQ,All]`, I don't get anything (nor with the option `Heads->True`). Any idea why?

Comment: I noticed that.  The same thing happens with `FreeQ`.  They unpack the packed arrays before scanning for expressions that match the pattern.,  I suppose they do it because they check all subexpressions from bottom up (at least that’s the order in which `Cases` returns expressions).  `ReplaceAll` goes top down.  ``Reap[expr /. x_?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> Sow[x]][[2,1]]` might be an alternative to `Cases`.  Plus it won’t return subarrays of packed arrays, which I surmise would be desirable.

Comment: Could you post a MCE (minimal crashing example)?